# Show all taxonomy terms on taxonomy term page

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

Though I saw a lot of posts on views & terms, this is new it seems.

I have a set of 1-level vocabularies. When user is on term page

```
mysite.com/vocabulary1/term1/
```

He should see also 'menu' - list of all terms of this vocabulary.

How can it be achieved?

P.S. I think that it's about context filters but I can't figure out how!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of modules to solve this purpose

- [Taxonomy Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_block)
- [Taxonomy Menu Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block)

Here is the config page of taxonomy menu block module

[image]